# Oracle Jet not displaying data from web service

Tags: javascript, oracle, knockout.js, oracle-adf, oracle-jet

I have been using Oracle ADF for quite sometime now and would like to implement Oracle JET for a better look and feel front end. I already downloaded all the files and follow the docs for the setup. I downloaded the CRUD sample and it works fine. The issue is that when I change the web service URL I start seeing all of this errors on the browser inspector(Chrome) saying that failed to load resource: server responded with a status of 404 not found. Specifically the Knockout library and Require Js.

```
Failed to load resource: server responded with a status of 404 not found.
```

I woukld greatly appreciated if someone explain to me the purpose of Knockout and Require Js on JET and how I can display my web service data using JET in conjunction with ADF. Thank you.

Comment: This is an old thread. Wanted to know if it has been solved. If it is not due to  backend Server resource issue, please check to see if your GET request for the resource has been set to "async : false".

Comment: Don't use OJET with ADF, it just complicates things for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer the question with just the info that you've provided. Can you give the version of Oracle JET that you are using, which OS, and which version of Chrome please?

If everything was working, and you only changed the URL that the REST call is going to, then the 404 error is most likely the REST endpoint that you are trying to reach and not something like Knockout and RequireJS missing. You may very well be seeing those libraries mentioned in the call stack, but I doubt that they are the ones missing.

Can you reach the REST endpoint from the browser directly by just putting that URL into the browser address bar?

Comment: Im using the verison 2.0.0, Chrome 49.0.2623.112m, and windows 7.Actually I put the URL directly in the browser and it displays the data. I manage to use the CDN and now it works but I wanna know what was causing the error I got.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: v2.0.0 is a really old version of JET and probably has something going on that is fixed in the newer releases.  When you say you used CDN, what did you use it for? (JET libraries, other libraries, ??)  There isn't enough information to give a definitive reason on why it failed in 2.0.0, but now works.